# django dev server, adding headers to static files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Using the django dev server (1.7.4), I want to add some headers to all the static files it serves.

It looks like I can pass a custom view to `django.conf.urls.static.static`, like so:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from common.views.static import serve

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
        document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT, view=serve)
```

And `common.views.static.serve` looks like this:

```
from django.views.static import serve as static_serve

def serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    """
    An override to `django.views.static.serve` that will allow us to add our
    own headers for development.

    Like `django.views.static.serve`, this should only ever be used in
    development, and never in production.
    """
    response = static_serve(request, path, document_root=document_root,
        show_indexes=show_indexes)

    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

However, simply having `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS` adds the static urls automatically, and there doesn't seem to be a way to override them.  Removing `django.contrib.staticfiles` from `INSTALLED_APPS` makes this work, however, if I do that, the staticfiles templatetags are no longer available.

How can I override the headers that are served for static files using the django development server?

Comment: hmmm, I assume you have your reasons, but could you not achieve this by defining the headers as an include within a block on a generic template and then extend that template on your actual templates.

Comment: It's not for html files, it's for font files.

Comment: oh, ok.  well, like I said, I assumed you had your reasons which is why I didn't write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`staticfiles` app [overrides the core `runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#runserver) command but allows you to disable the automatic serving of the static files:

```
python manage.py runserver --nostatic
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the code of the author did not work for me, I would get errors like:

```
[10/Dec/2020 18:08:13] "GET /static/img/foo.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 10482
Not Found: /static/img/foo.svg
```

I am using Django 3 if that makes a difference.

This is what I did:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve

def custom_serve(request, path, insecure=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Customize the response of serving static files.

    Note:
        This should only ever be used in development, and never in production.
    """
    response = serve(request, path, insecure=True)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    # if path.endswith('sw.js'):
    #    response['Service-Worker-Allowed'] = '/'
    return response
```

the urls part is the same as the question:

```py
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Allow custom static file serving (use with manage.py --nostatic)
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from CHANGE.THIS.PATH.views import custom_serve
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT, view=custom_serve
    )
```