# django No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error on static file

Tags: python, angularjs, django, static

Hello I am trying to open CSV file on an angularjs app front end using

```
  var fieldsDocumentationAssetUrl = pythonApiBaseUrl + '/static/docs/fields_documentation_asset_api.csv';
  var promise = $http.get(fieldsDocumentationAssetUrl).then(function(response){
     $scope.fieldsDocumentationAsset = CommonUtils.processCsvFile(response.data);
  });
```

That file is hosted on the django/python backend. I'm getting the error below but in general I am able to serve static files and this docs folder is in the static files directory. I have the django staticfiles app in installed apps, etc. How can I serve this file?

Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5555/static/docs/api/fields_documentation_asset_api.csv. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: You are running a server on both port 5555 and port 8000?

Comment: Yes - frontend (angularjs app) is port 8000 and backend (python/django) is port 5555

Comment: So you should set a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the csv file for angular to use it.

Comment: Check out this question for how to do that with the dev server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724951/django-dev-server-adding-headers-to-static-files