# How to show django ImageField in browser URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a webscraping app that downloads images from a website and stores it in an ImageField of one of my models.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=300)
    url = models.CharField('URL', max_length=200)
    hero_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', max_length=255)
```

My `hero_image` field looks like this in my project: "http://localhost:8000/media/pictures/gettyimages-585288019.jpgw210h158crop1quality85stripall"

And the images are stored at `myproject/myproject/pictures`:

```
myproject
├── myproject
│   ├── settings.py
├── pictures
├── manage.py
```

When I click the sample link above I automatically download the image, but instead I would like to show the image in the browser.

### What I've done so far

**myproject/urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'', include('core.urls')),
]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

There are a lot of topics similar to my question on SO but I've read a bunch of them and still can't find one that seems to help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click the sample link above I automatically download the image, but instead I would like to show the image in the browser.

This is determined by the web server. If you set the HTTP header `Content-Disposition: inline`, it's an instruction to the web browser to open the image in the browser instead of treating it as a file download.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Most web servers such as Apache or Nginx will set this header by default for all image files.

If you want to add the `Content-Disposition` header to files served by the `runserver` development server, you might have to override the default method. See this question for details.

[django dev server, adding headers to static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724951/django-dev-server-adding-headers-to-static-files)